# External Monitor Limited to 1920x 1080

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, display-resolution

I have an HP Envy Dv7 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed and when I am just doing work I like to hook it up to my Dell S2716DG via an HDMI cable, however, I cannot seem to run the monitor at its native resolution 2560x 1440.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B077XVN4P7/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077XVN4P7)

My first thought was that 2560x 1440 was not supported by my HDMI cable, however, I am able to get this resolution connecting through the same cable on my home server computer that has a Nvidia GTX 680, my laptop has a 650m. Does the resolution cap have anything to do with the 650m card and the integrated Intel graphics or is there something I can do to get the external monitor to run at its native resolution?

If it isn't obvious I like using Ubuntu but I'm not the most knowledgable about it. Thank you to anyone who can help me with this.